# Autopilot's Collect feature can't deal with accentuation

Tags: twilio

I know Autopilot doesn't support Portuguese, but this is a major bummer.

My bot asks a "yes or no" question (sim ou não) and if the answer is without accentuation (nao), it doesn't understand it means 'não'.

I can't even type in 'nao' as a synonym in the custom field type, it says 'FieldValue already in use'.

I asked the Twillio support 9 days ago and haven't got a reply yet. What do you guys think? Is there a way around this? =/

Comment: hi there! It's a chat or sms bot? what's the Assistant SID?

Comment: Hi! It's a whatsapp chatbot, the Assistant SSID is UA313a4235eb1ee7cc39ce2ec1781d911a

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

- The Autopilot speech recognition engine is only working for English, so the transcribed text will always be in English: having "não" as a field value won't work for queries like "nao", but it would be helpful to add "nao" as a field value with synonym "não".
- It seems your assistant does not have samples with fields which means if you do not use the `Collect` Action, those values will never get recognized even when not using voice, since the model does not have those values. Using `Collect` will be useful in your case; otherwise, I think you should add samples with fields to certain tasks.

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: "it would be helpful to add "nao" as a field value with synonym "não""
When I do it, it says 'FieldValue already in use nao'

Regarding the lack of samples, I know, but it's ok.

Comment: The Autopilot team is on it! It looks like a bug in how unicode is handled on our end

Comment: Great to hear it! Can you please let me know when it's fixed?